# Android server: Parse server gradle build

Tags: java, android, parsing, server, sdk

[image]Hey guys im sorry this is a nooby question. But i cant figure this out.

My PROBLEM: Im trying to set up a parse server in my android studio project , I was told to set it up I need to " try adding compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.14.1'into dependencies ,and synchronize your grid." However when I do this I get a bunch of errors. I will gadly share the error logs also. Here is my code

```js
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("")
            .clientKey("")
            .server("")
            .build()
    );

    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ExampleObject");
    object.put("myNumber", "123");
    object.put("myString", "rob");

    object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException ex) {
        if (ex == null) {
          Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
        } else {
          Log.i("Parse Result", "Failed" + ex.toString());
        }
      }
    });


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

  }
}
```

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.karanvir.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: You need to add ` 'com.parse:parse-android:1.14.1` into the dependencies object. I don't see that you've done that

Comment: please look at my screenshot

Comment: I POSTED THE ANSWER HERE
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070221/parse-server-android-studio-not-showing-information/45089318?noredirect=1#comment77178426_45089318

Comment: i posted my answer here thanks everyone
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070221/parse-server-android-studio-not-showing-information/45089318?noredirect=1#comment77178426_45089318**

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    //place it here just like this
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.14.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: install the annotation repository it suggests. Just click on the link it gives